Number searches in Solr returning decimals
We are looking for some help with Solr and number searches.  When users search for a number such as 23019, decimals such as 230.19 are returned.  Another example is a search on 3373.  A file with 33.73 was returned.  We would like to only get results that have that exact number in it—23019 or 3373.  Can you help us with the configuration? A third example is a search on 901 is returning files with 90.1 in it.  But we just want hits that say 901.
We are running Solr 7.2.1.
I'm pretty sure we need to update the schema.xml but I'm not sure what to change.

Is it the suggester component that you are using for getting the search results?

It'll depend on what the field type for the field is - sounds like you're using a text field to store numbers, so if you only want to have exact matches, you can either use a numeric field that matches the decimals you want, or you can use a string field - a string field only match when the content is exactly the same.

@MatsLindh I should have mentioned that I am a novice to Solr.  So I'm trying to work on something I don't fully understand.   There are several fieldTypes defined in my schema.xml.  I think I know which one is being used but how can you tell for sure?  I appreciate any help.

@user2260040 I am not sure of the suggester component you're referring to.

please post your schema.xml and sorlconfig.xml

@KemberliHolmes Your schema will have a field defined for the type you've defined (unless running in schemaless mode). Changing the field type - and reindexing (i.e. resubmitting) the content will change how it gets processed and how you can query the values afterwards.
